# MPI Init causes crash in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mpi

I am trying to get an MPI program to run, however it appears to crash on the MPI_INIT call.

Visual studio merely says the exe "has triggered a breakpoint", but doesn't tell me anything else. I am trying to run with 4 processes.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int testNumber;
long wcTime, totalWcTime;
float cpuTime, totalCPUTime;

_totalTextLength = 0;
totalWcTime = 0;
totalCPUTime = 0;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
```

The call stack is as follows:
[image]

Comment: As I usually answer with such questions, I haven't seen any MS-MPI questions answered here. You'll probably need to go through their official support channels here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx